# удаление apache2 с ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

Как полностью удалить apache2 с ubuntu 14.04 ?

Удалял так  sudo apt-get autoremove apache2. Но он все равно запускается!

Comment: А так пробовали `sudo apt-get remove --purge apache2`?

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov, пишет: Package 'apache2' is not installed, so not removed
 но при  вызове lacalhost  он все равно запускается.

Comment: значит, устанавливали «вручную». чтобы действительно удалить, вспоминайте инструкции, по которой это сделали. и делайте «реверс».

Comment: Предполагаю, что это вообще не *Apache*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Может он не удаляется, так как еще запущен, а система сама не смогла по каким-то причинам его остановить. Попробуйте его остановить сначала.

***/etc/init.d/apache2 stop***

или

***service apache2 stop***

И только после остановки удаляйте его.

2. Попробуйте удалить не только его, но и сопутствующие пакеты, которые укажите

***apt-get purge apache2 apache2-utils apache2.2-bin apache2-common***

3. Все действия (и поиск в том числе) выполняйте под рутом.
   Что выдает

***whereis apache2***

Answer (score 0):

Удали всё, что выплюнет комманда

```
aptitude search apache2 | egrep ^i
```

Comment: ничего не выплюнула

Comment: А как апач был установлен? make && make install ?

Comment: sudo apt-get install apache2

Comment: Хм... а если его ещё раз поставить? Именно через apt-get.